# Translate MySQL to JPA

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, eclipselink

I'm trying to translate a MySQL query to JPA.

I'm using MySQL5 and EclipseLink 2.4.2.

Here's the MySQL query :

```
SELECT s.id, s.startDate, CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT s.endDate ORDER BY s.date DESC) AS DATE) endDate
FROM table_s s
WHERE ...
GROUP BY s.id, s.startDate
```

`id` and `date` are primary key. They are represented by an embeddable id in JPA and fields are also readable in the entity (insertable/updatable = false).

Here's the JPA query :

```
SELECT s.id, s.startDate, SQL('CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ? ORDER BY ? DESC) AS DATE)', s.endDate, s.date) AS endDate
FROM EntityS s
WHERE ...
GROUP BY s.id, s.startDate
```

The current issue is that the generated sql query does not include `s.startDate` for a reason I don't know.

If I simply change the code to `SELECT s.id, s.startDate, s.endDate`, it's working... but I really need to get the last `endDate`.

I tried `MAX(s.endDate)` but actually it does not give the last value (even if it currently works, it's not correct and can send a wrong result)

If someone got an idea or a solution, I would be pleased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I made it otherwise :

```
SELECT s.id, s.startDate, s.endDate
FROM EntityS s
WHERE ...
AND s.date = (
    SELECT MAX(s.date)
    FROM EntityS s2
    WHERE s2.id = s.id
    AND s2.startDate = s.startDate
    AND ...
)
GROUP BY s.id, s.startDate
```